# Why does an Arduino Uno have 2 microcontrollers

Tags: arduino-uno

I was looking at this [schematic:](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf) [image]

And I noticed that there are 2 microcontrollers (an Atmega328p and a ATmega16U2).  I was wondering why there need to be 2 microcontrollers.  Do they do different things that only 1 of them can do and the other can't ?

Comment: *Why does an Arduino Uno have 3 microcontrollers* - is this a typo? You have only identified two of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atmega328P is a microcontroller which are the heart of Arduino Uno, where the Atmega8U2 is the USB to serial convertor for arduino communicated with computer.

You can refer to this [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUnoSMD) for more information about this.